# Error while using string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm assigning a variable as such:

```
cmd="sed -i 's/id="556"/id="33442233"\n    pss="120"/g' a.xml"
```

But when im trying to print cmd im getting a syntax error, seems it's
because of multiple `'` and `"`... how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Escape the quotes using `\` ?

```
cmd="sed -i 's/id=\"556\"/id=\"33442233\"\n pss=\"120\"/g' a.xml"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use triple quotes:

```
cmd = '''sed -i 's/id="556"/id="33442233"\n pss="120"/g' a.xml'''
```

Btw. I see `\n` there - if you want to keep it as backslash-n and not have it converted to a single newline character, you can even use this:

```
cmd = r'''sed -i 's/id="556"/id="33442233"\n pss="120"/g' a.xml'''
```

Answer (score 1):

To escape quotes, put a backslash `\` before the character. For example:
`"\"hello\" said he."` and `'\'goodbye\' said she'`

Answer (score 0):

worked for me:

```
Python 2.7.9 (v2.7.9:648dcafa7e5f, Dec 10 2014, 10:10:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> cmd="sed -i \'s\/id=\"556\"\/id=\"33442233\"\n    pss=\"120\"\/g\' a.xml"
>>> print cmd
sed -i 's\/id="556"\/id="33442233"
    pss="120"\/g' a.xml
```